# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.” With SSL Certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

```
public static bool DataCheck(string RefNo, out string region)
{
    region = "";

    try
    {
        string url = "https://plugin.comapny.com/api/DataCheck";

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            Jobvalidation JVObj = new Jobvalidation();
            JVObj.RefNo = RefNo.ToUpper();
            JVObj.ConnectionString = Configration.DMSConfig.Connectionstring;
            JVObj.Zone = Configration.DMSConfig.ZONE;
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");
            string result = client.UploadString(url, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JVObj));
            JVObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Jobvalidation>(result);
            region = JVObj.region;
            bool flag = Convert.ToBoolean(JVObj.flag);
            return flag;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //string result;
        region = "Exception:" + ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

when we hit the service from local machines we are getting the above error. above is my code could you please check and help for this

Comment: Probably you need to change TLS like this:
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: if you are using https,you need to send client certificate as well.